# In five card draw poker, are there variants with multiple tiers of betting?

Tags: 5-card-draw, variant

Is there a variant of draw poker where the bet is x before the draw and 2x afterwards? If so, how might that change your strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that was a common structure in California in the 80s and 90s. You should be inclined to draw more often and bluff more often than in a flat-limit game.